# find matches of list a in b and return list c

Tags: indexing, match

So i have the following 3 lists and needs to create a 4th:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
b = ['21', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '12', '11', '10', '7', '6', '3', '2']
c = ['1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1', '0', '0', '1']
```

a is always the same.
b and c always have equal lengths, but the length can vary.
Values of b is always between 1 and 25.
Values of c is always 0 or 1.

I need to create:

```
d =[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

where for every item in a, i search in b and return the value in c.

I got about 3000 different sets of b and c, so trying to create something efficient, and haven't been able to figure out a good way to do this.

Comment: Map/dict can help where key is going to be one from b while value is going to be associated value in c (i note string vs integer but i am getting that may be a typo).

Comment: When you say "search in `b`" do you mean find that index in `b` and use that as an index into `c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this with just two lines, by creating a dict that maps values of b to values of c. Then you go through a and at each letter you check if it exists within the lookup dict:

```
lookup = {b_val: c_val for b_val, c_val in zip(b, c)}
d = [lookup[str(a_val)] if str(a_val) in lookup else "0" for a_val in a]
```

This should have O(n) time complexity where n is max((len(a), len(b))).

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
def get_value(A,D,x):
    if x in D: return D[x]
    return '0'

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
b = ['21', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '12', '11', '10', '7', '6', '3', '2']
c = ['1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '0',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1', '0', '0', '1']

map_b_to_c = dict(list(zip(b,c)))

d = [get_value(a, map_b_to_c, str(x)) for x in a]
print(d)
```